# My button doesn't work on KendoUI Window

Tags: javascript, asp.net, kendo-ui

I have a KendoUI window component in Default.aspx, and it show a div(by id=window2) which has two textboxes, a label and a button on popup, my div :

```
 <div id="window2" style="display: none; direction: rtl; ">

       <input id="userName" style="direction: rtl" type="text" value="" />

       <asp:Label ID="lbl1" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>         

       <input id="password" style="direction: rtl; margin-right: 44px" type="password"    value="" class="keyboardInput" />

       <asp:Button ID="enterLogin" runat="server" Text="ENTER" OnClick="enterLogin_Click" />
```

and in the Default.aspx I have :

```
  protected void enterLogin_Click( object sender, EventArgs e )
    {
       lbl1.Text = "hiiiiiiiii";
     }
```

but, when I click on enterLogin, it doesn't do anything. What is the problem?

EDIT: my script for windows is :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function ()
    {
           function initWindow2()
        {
            var windowOptions = {
                width: "350px",
                title: "Login",
                modal: true,
                visible: false,

                positiontop: -100,
            };

            $("#window2").kendoWindow(windowOptions);
            $("#window2").data("kendoWindow").center().open();
        }

      $("#enter").bind("click", function ()
        {

            initWindow2();

        });
        $("#cancelLogin").bind("click", function ()
        {

            $("#window2").data("kendoWindow").close();

        });
    });
</script>
```

Notice: when I click on a div by id=enter, it pops up the window2, which contain label, textbox and button.

Comment: Would you please share the rendered html result of `window2` in your browser? Also move the `enterLogin` button out of the `window2` and check if it works correctly? If yes share it's html too.

Comment: Yes, i do as you said and it worked,, i find another solution

Comment: so answer to your question and accept it and let people know [how] you solved your problem.

Comment: My solution may not be a good way (people may give me negative point:) ), but it help me. i explain you here, i put an another asp button (by id=btn1) on page(put it out of the window2) and on it's button-click event i define my function and then make it invisible, then by Jquery i define a function which i click on enterLogin (my asp button on window2) it called btn1's event click. Just this.